# Detect HSQLDB failure to initialize due to corruption

Tags: java, hsqldb

When starting an embedded HSQLDB it sometimes logs exceptions:

```
2016-11-08 10:35:27 INFO h.d.H.ENGINE user:NA company:NA remotehost:NA dataFileCache open start
2016-11-08 10:35:27 INFO h.d.H.ENGINE user:NA company:NA remotehost:NA dataFileCache open end
2016-11-08 10:35:31 ERROR h.d.H.ENGINE user:NA company:NA remotehost:NA statement error processing log /home/jetty/test/testdb/test.dbline: 87137
org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.FROM
        at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
        at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
        at org.hsqldb.SchemaManager.getUserTable(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
        at org.hsqldb.scriptio.ScriptReaderText.processStatement(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
        at org.hsqldb.scriptio.ScriptReaderText.readLoggedStatement(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
        at org.hsqldb.persist.ScriptRunner.runScript(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
        at org.hsqldb.persist.ScriptRunner.runScript(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
        at org.hsqldb.persist.Log.processLog(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
        at org.hsqldb.persist.Log.open(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
        at org.hsqldb.persist.Logger.openPersistence(Unknown Source) [hsqldb-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
        at org.hsqldb.Database.reopen(Unknown Source) [hsqldb-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
        at org.hsqldb.Database.open(Unknown Source) [hsqldb-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
        at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.getDatabase(Unknown Source) [hsqldb-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
        at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.newSession(Unknown Source) [hsqldb-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.<init>(Unknown Source) [hsqldb-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source) [hsqldb-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.connect(Unknown Source) [hsqldb-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:95) [HikariCP-2.4.3.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:101) [HikariCP-2.4.3.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:314) [HikariCP-2.4.3.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:171) [HikariCP-2.4.3.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:436) [HikariCP-2.4.3.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.access$500(HikariPool.java:65) [HikariCP-2.4.3.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:567) [HikariCP-2.4.3.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:560) [HikariCP-2.4.3.jar:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_51]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_51]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_51]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_51]
2016-11-08 10:35:31 INFO h.d.H.ENGINE user:NA company:NA remotehost:NA checkpointClose start
2016-11-08 10:35:31 INFO h.d.H.ENGINE user:NA company:NA remotehost:NA dataFileCache commit start
2016-11-08 10:35:31 INFO h.d.H.ENGINE user:NA company:NA remotehost:NA checkpointClose end
2016-11-08 10:35:32 INFO c.x.p.d.u.DataSourceFactory user:NA company:NA remotehost:NA Database connection is OK!
2016-11-08 10:35:32 INFO c.x.p.d.u.DataSourceFactory user:NA company:NA remotehost:NA Initialising data source: Liquibase
2016-11-08 10:35:32 INFO c.x.p.d.u.DataSourceFactory user:NA company:NA remotehost:NA HSQLDB used
```

It seems like HSQLDB swallows these exceptions.
This results in our java code to continue to run even though the DB might be corrupt.

Is there a way to catch these exceptions?
Or an Java API call to verify that the DB is correctly started?

Comment: Can you post your code where you are accessing the database ?

Comment: Version 2.2.7 was quickly replaced with 2.2.8 due to a persistence issue. At least switch to that version if not the latest.

Comment: @javaguy we're not evening querying the DB yet. This happens when HSQLDB is being initialized.
The HSQLDB is initialized through Hikari:
`hikariConnPool.setDriverClassName(org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver.class.getName());
hikariConnPool.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:hsqldb:" + Configuration.databasePath);`

Comment: @fredt apart from bumping the version, is there a way to detect such an exceptions when being thrown

Comment: Connection fails when such an exception is thrown and it is fatal. It succeeds when it is not fatal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception message blow:

```
org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.FROM
```

indicates in the .log file of the database there is a reference to a table named `FROM` in line 87137 of the .log file. As a table cannot be called `FROM` it shows there is a mangled line.

This can happen when the database was not shutdown properly and the last lines of the .log file are not synced to disk. The engine ignores the .log file entries from that point.

You have the option of adding `hsqldb.full_log_replay=true` to the connection properties in order to throw the exception and to abort the connection attempt. You can then view and edit the .log file to remove the mangled lines.
If you want to